# Stability of passive networks

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, stability, network

Generally we see that  single Port electrical networks (LTI system) that contains resistors and other passive elements are stable .
So is it safe to assume that
passivity(absorbs power) of electrical network is sufficient condition for its stability
or
There may be cases where network consist of resistors and other passive elements is unstable?

Comment: Is this static stability, or do you include annoying things like thermal drift?

Comment: Only lyapunov stability and bibo stability

Comment: Too broad - needs focus - an "electrical network" could mean anything. Be specific and encompassing with your definition.

Comment: Ok,I edited to Make it specific to single Port electrical network(LTI system) , but if I Make it even more specific then there might be loss of generality , that's why I asked general passive electrical single Port network and it's relation with stability because I wanted to understand how  stability and passivity of a system related to each other

Comment: Passive components by themselves are fundamentally stable. What is your real question / motive here?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am interested in a mathematical relation which  proves that passivity  implies stability (I.e if passivity implies stability ,is true then there must be some mathematical relation should exist that's what I'm interested in, and if it is false then there must be some counter example to prove my assumption wrong

Comment: @user215805 That proof will require some creativity. Part of that will involve visualizing the number of ways that N two-terminal passive parts can be combined inside a two-port network model. Without imagination, this will determine a subset of numerator and denominator polynomial coefficients that are possible using non-zero positive values for each component. Then some creativity/imagination is needed to "see" the needed characteristics to make the proof. This is more for the mathematics side of stack exchange. But I'm sure there's already a paper on it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an RLC network of passive components will be stable, because they only delay or absorb power.

A direct effect of BIBO stability is that the transfer function is absolutely integrable:
$$ \int_0^\infty \biggl|h(t)\biggr| \, dt \lt \infty $$

Which for any real load (finite impedance) means that the energy output is finite for any finite input.  Lyapunov stability relies heavily on the idea of energy transfer, to great effect even in non-linear systems.

With a network of passives, there is no energy source other than the input; with any resistance at all, the output energy will always be less than the input energy.

Stability generally becomes a concern with feedback.  For instance an op-amp circuit with positive feedback will eventually max out its output.

Comment: I don't understand how does power absorption related to stability of a RLC circuit. What if poles of that network is on or right side of y-axis of s-plane?

Comment: @Sanmvegsaini The LHS criterion is a formalism for negative gain (feedback); how can you have positive gain if the input is the only source of power/energy?  Look at the transfer function for a specific RLC network; any (positive) R will push the poles into the LHS.